# Fourier series expansion of a phase shifted quasi-square wave

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to evaluate the trigonometric Fourier series expansions of three quasi-square waves, which are essentially the same quasi-square waveform, phase-shifted with respect to each other by multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. The three waveforms are as shown:

[Phase-shifted quasi-square waveforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcUd4.png)

$$
S_a(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & : 0 ≤ x < \frac{\pi}{6} \\
1 & : \frac{\pi}{6} ≤ x < \frac{5\pi}{6} \\
0 & : \frac{5\pi}{6} ≤ x < \frac{7\pi}{6} \\
-1 & : \frac{7\pi}{6} ≤ x < \frac{11\pi}{6} \\
0 & : \frac{11\pi}{6} ≤ x < {2\pi} \\
S_a((x \mod 2\pi)) & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$$S_b(x)=S_a(x-\frac{2\pi}{3})$$
$$S_c(x)=S_a(x-\frac{4\pi}{3})$$

I have evaluated the Fourier series of the first waveform (in red) and the Fourier coefficients are as follows:

$$a_{0}^r = 0$$
$$a_{n}^r = 0$$
$$b_{n}^r = \begin{cases}
\frac{4}{n\pi}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{6}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I am trying to approximate the Fourier coefficients for the other two waveforms from these coefficients. I know that for a complex Fourier series expansion, the time-shifting property of the Fourier series gives:

$$\operatorname{FourierSeriesCoeff}(f(x-x_0))=C_n'=C_{n}e^{-jnx_0}$$
where, $\operatorname{FourierSeriesCoeff}(f(x))=C_{n}$

I also know the relationship between the complex $C_n$ and trigonometric Fourier coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ as:
$$C_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-jb_n)$$
$$C_{-n}=C_{n}^*=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+jb_n)$$

Combining the expressions above gives the following:

$$C_n'=\frac{1}{2}(a_n'-jb_n')=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-jb_n)e^{-jnx_0}$$
$$C_{-n}'=\frac{1}{2}(a_n'+jb_n')=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+jb_n)e^{-jnx_0}$$

Using Euler's formula $e^{-jnp}=cos(np)-jsin(np)$ and solving for $a_n'$ and $b_n'$, I get:

$$a_n'= a_n\cos(nx_0)-b_n\sin(nx_0)$$
$$b_n'= a_n\sin(nx_0)+b_n\cos(nx_0)$$

Using these for my initial problem, I should get for the blue waveform:

$$a_n^b= a_n^r\cos(\frac{n2\pi}{3})-b_n^r\sin(\frac{n2\pi}{3})$$
$$b_n^b= a_n^r\sin(\frac{n2\pi}{3})+b_n^r\cos(\frac{n2\pi}{3})$$

which resolves to:

$$a_n^b= \begin{cases}
-b_n^r\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$b_n^b= \begin{cases}
b_n^r\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

However, after trying to evaluate the trigonometric coefficients for the blue waveform manually, I have the following expression for $a_n^b$:

$$a_n^b=\frac{1}{n\pi}[-3sin(\frac{2n\pi}{3})cos(\frac{n\pi}{6})+cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})sin(\frac{n\pi}{6})-sin(\frac{n\pi}{6})]$$

What am I doing wrong? I am attaching my attempt at a solution here:
[My Attempt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zAgqnjk4FxFCvEOQmg_pvvFssDAleK5N/view?usp=sharing)

Edit 1: I was unable to simplify the expression for the manual calculation. However, after verifying with Mathematica, the coefficients follow the time-shifting property correctly, which is what I was trying to verify. The Fourier coefficients for the the three waveforms end up being:

$$a_{n}^r = 0$$
$$b_{n}^r = \begin{cases}
\frac{4}{n\pi}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{6}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$$a_{n}^b= \begin{cases}
-b_n^r\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$b_n^b= \begin{cases}
b_n^r\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$$a_{n}^o = -a_{n}^b= \begin{cases}
b_n^r\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{3}) & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$b_n^o= b_{n}^b = \begin{cases}
b_n^r\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})  & : n\ \text{odd except triplen} \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

[Here's the result from Mathematica](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ENIasHMLcpr-xw8IG-KGX_L8scjdi7W0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: A more detailed attempt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oP5GQmYV4XkdbUC-u4h9FJBhRrfzrG6I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Mathematica indicates your last formula is equivalent to $$a_n^b=-\frac{3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)}{\pi  n}$$ using the assumption $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for responding Steven. I have arrived at the same result myself through hand calc, but it doesn't seem to match the value from the time-shifting property. I have edited the question to reflect both values now.

Comment: Could you please clarify if $$S_a(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0\leq x<\frac{\pi }{3} \\
 1 & \frac{\pi }{3}\leq x<\frac{2 \pi }{3} \\
 0 & \frac{2 \pi }{3}\leq x<\frac{4 \pi }{3} \\
 -1 & \frac{4 \pi }{3}\leq x<\frac{5 \pi }{3} \\
 0 & \frac{5 \pi }{3}\leq x<\frac{6 \pi }{3} \\
S_a((x \bmod (2 \pi ))) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.$$ is the correct definition of $S_a(x)$, and the value of the constants $x_b$ and $x_c$ in $S_b(x)=S_a(x-x_b)$ and $S_c(x)=S_a(x-x_c)$?

Comment: Hello Steven, I am terribly sorry for wasting your time. It seems I should have provided an equation for the waveform at the start. I have updated the problem statement to reflect the correct equation for the waveform. I am redoing the solution since I seem to have written my last solution using the wrong angle values.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.